# Como fazer uma div passa do tamanho da grid?

Tags: html, css, grid

Gente, gostaria de deixar dessa forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas ate agora, só consegui deixar assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou o css grid, não consigo fazer a div passar pra cima da outra. Meus códigos:

```css
#sobre {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.9fr 1.1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 1px 1px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "logo descricao";
  align-items: center;
}
#sobre .logo {
  grid-area: logo;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px -10px #000000;
  justify-self: end;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#sobre .descricao {
  grid-area: descricao;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px -10px #000000;
  justify-self: start;
  padding: 30px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<section id="sobre">
    <div class="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="descricao flexboxContainer">
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: já tentou usar `position: absolute`?

Comment: Ja, mas ai se eu usar a div sai das propriedade do grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara existe mais de uma forma de configurar o `Grid` para ter esse resultado, mas basicamente o que vc está tentando fazer se chama "**Grid Overlap**" *(e sinceramente eu não sei porque deram -1 na sua pergunta... Infelizmente estamos vivendo esse momento tóxico aqui no Stackoverflow)*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Continuando a resposta, basicamente vc pode fazer esse `overlap` numerando as `columns` ou usando o `grid-area` como vc fez, mas fazendo um `span` de 1 coluna para dentro da outra tipo `grid-column: logo / span 5;`

Outra coisa importante que vc precisa fazer e definir **explicitamente** que as duas células vão ocupar a mesma `row`, se vc não fizer isso a coluna maior vai quebrar para a linha de baixo, para isso coloque `grid-row: 1;` nas `divs` do `grid`.

Basicamente é isso. Se vc quiser testar de um jeito diferente é só comentar as propriedades repetidas e descomentar o que eu deixei comentado...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#sobre {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;

  /* distancia entre os elementos do grid e a lateral da página */
  padding: 0 10%;

  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr); */
  /* grid-auto-rows: 1fr; */
  grid-template-areas: "logo logo logo logo descricao descricao descricao descricao descricao descricao";
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 1px 1px;
  align-items: center;
}

#sobre .logo {
  grid-row: 1;
  /* grid-column: 1 / 4; */
  grid-column: logo / span 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px -10px #000000;
  justify-self: end;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#sobre .descricao {
  grid-row: 1;
  /* grid-column: 3 / 11; */
  grid-area: descricao;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px -10px #000000;
  justify-self: start;
  padding: 30px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<section id="sobre">
  <div class="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="descricao flexboxContainer">
  </div>
</section>
```

Esse artigo pode te ajudar a entender melhor a técnica: https://gridbyexample.com/learn/2016/12/20/learning-grid-day20/

Comment: vlw mano, ajudou dms

Comment: @william dmr boa sorte ai!